# Resource Routing: short style

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

here is my `config/routes.rb`:

```
Eesoudayo::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

...which, as you can imagine, generates the following routes:

```
    article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                     POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
 new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
     article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                     PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                     DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
```

My question is: *is there a sexy way to clean a little bit them, giving this result?*

```
    article_comments GET    /:article_id/(.:format)         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                     POST   /:article_id/(.:format)         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
 new_article_comment GET    /:article_id/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
edit_article_comment GET    /:article_id/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
     article_comment GET    /:article_id/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                     PUT    /:article_id/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                     DELETE /:article_id/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
            articles GET    /.:format)                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
                     POST   /.:format)                      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
         new_article GET    /new(.:format)                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}
        edit_article GET    /:id/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}
             article GET    /:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}
                     PUT    /:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}
                     DELETE /:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
```

---

PS: I'm working with Rails 3.x <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know if this works, a shot in the dark really:

```
Eesoudayo::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles, :path => "/" do
    resources :comments, :path => "/"
  end
end
```

I have only tested this using `rake routes`, it may very well be that everything will explode when you try to launch your server.

Comment: I love trying things while telling myself "there's no way this could work" and finding out it works :-)